# How can I add (e.g. "add to group") to membership search results or other Action lists?

Tags: civimember

Our Membership chair entered all of our membership records without assigning them to a group ("Members") but "Add to Group" is not an option in the Membership report screen as it is in other search screens. I don't find a way to add that Action in the Custom Fields, Profiles, or any other menu that I have checked.This is likely to come up in other contexts and similar mods can be done in other areas, so there may be an easy way to do this that I can't find. Otherwise I will have to go in and modify each record.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

So there is this perverse magic - wash your car and it rains, get in the shower and the phone rings. Post a question on Stack Exchange and find your answer eight minutes later.
If you go to Reports | Membership Reports | Membership Details, the default action is "Add to a Group".
Now if I only had a group for Impatient Idiots, I could add myself.